# Lambda context returning {value: ''} instead of {'key': value}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get the value of the key in querystring in my AWS API Gateway.

In my route, I have something like `/server_ip` that accepts a `device_id` querystring.

However, when I make a GET request to `/server_ip?device_id=10`,

I'm getting
`{'10': ''}` instead of `{'device_id': '10'}`

In my **Body Mapping Templates** I've got:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "device_id": "$input.params('device_id')"
}
```

In my lambda function I've got:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var deviceId = require('querystring').parse(event.device_id);
    callback(null, deviceId);
};
```

Am I doing this right? Please point me to the right direction.
Thanks

## Solved

Turns out the `require('querystring')` is a **big** no no.

Directly accessing `event.device_id` returns the expected `{'device_id': '10'}`. Must have followed an outdated tutorial.

Comment: Guessing: `callback(null, { device_id: deviceId });`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hello Michael, that would return {'device_id': {'device_id':'' }} This is solved, I'll update the post in a bit.